# Atom autocomplete adding a <

Tags: html, editor, atom-editor

When using Atom autocomplete, it adds an additional <.

Example <div (then I hit tab to use auto complete) generates

```
<<div class="">
</div>
```

I've searched around but sadly cannot find anything about atom adding extra characters. I'm sure this is something super simple and I am overlooking it... please let me know, thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-html/issues/97 this might help the issue has been brought up on github

Answer (score 1):

I found this by trial and error... but basically, instead of typing <html and then auto completing just type html and then autocomplete.

Another example, instead of typing <p and auto completing, just type p

Thanks everyone